# How to merge two tables overwriting the elements which are in both?

Tags: merge, lua, lua-table

I need to merge two tables, with the contents of the second overwriting contents in the first if a given item is in both.  I looked but the standard libraries don't seem to offer this. Where can I get such a function?

Comment: There is no single way of doing this.  Are you comparing the keys or the values in the table?  Is it possible for the keys / values to be other tables?...

Comment: i don't need any sort of comparison but i will be needing subtables...

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
for k,v in pairs(second_table) do first_table[k] = v end
```

Comment: wait, does that catch string keys and such?

Comment: This should work with some tweaking for handling subtables. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this overwrite what is currently in the table if the indices are the same, as would be in an array? If you had two tables with number keys [1],[2],[3] etc., one with data already in and you merely iterate over the second table's keys, also [1],[2],[3] etc. and add the data in the same positions with the same keys to table one, you'll overwrite whatever was originally there.

You could solve this with first_table[#first_table + k] = v.

Personally I'd go about this using tables.insert(), though not sure that was available in 2009!

Comment: I guess this is the price for maximum compactness. I have no problem with that, but reading this requires me to parse, compile, and execute this loop - all inside my brain! In other languages, you just need to remember a built-in way of doing it, like Python's `dict.update()`.

Comment: In 99% of the cases this will be the correct solution, but do keep in mind that in applications with tables that reference other tables, which is common in object-oriented patterns, you may need to do extra bookkeeping.

For instance, if there's some reason why the given table might reference itself directly, you'd want to check for `v==second_table` and, if so, assign `first_table` instead.  Tables can also reference themselves indirectly, but that's probably a book's worth of problems to solve.  I just wanted to put this on the radar, so 'nuff said.

Comment: @Astridax that is what the questioner asks for.

Answer (score 23):

Here's what i came up with based on Doug Currie's answer:

```
function tableMerge(t1, t2)
    for k,v in pairs(t2) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            if type(t1[k] or false) == "table" then
                tableMerge(t1[k] or {}, t2[k] or {})
            else
                t1[k] = v
            end
        else
            t1[k] = v
        end
    end
    return t1
end
```

Comment: Note that it is usually a bad idea to mess with standard Lua "namespaces" (like table.*). Better to make your own.

Comment: "if not t1[k] then t1[k] = {} end" contains a subtle bug (find it!)
Better write it as "t1[k] = t1[k] or {}".

Also, what happens if t2[k] is a table but t1[k] exists but is not a table?

Finally, "table1[k] = v" should be "t1[k] = v".

Comment: `tableMerge(t1[k] or {}, t2[k] or {})` would merge t2 into a new table and then discard that table. Maybe should be `t1[k] = tableMerge(t1[k] or {}, t2[k] or {})`.

Answer (score 14):

Wouldn't this work properly?

```
function merge(t1, t2)
    for k, v in pairs(t2) do
        if (type(v) == "table") and (type(t1[k] or false) == "table") then
            merge(t1[k], t2[k])
        else
            t1[k] = v
        end
    end
    return t1
end
```

Comment: Yes, but if you look at RCIX's original post, there was some different logic in there that was later simplified to two identical `else` statements. It should have been further simplified into what you have here.

Comment: Can anyone explain why `t1[k] or false` is necessary here?

Answer (score 8):

For numeric-index table merging:

```
for k,v in pairs(secondTable) do table.insert(firstTable, v) end
```

Comment: Isn't this solution wrong (as `pairs` is not guaranteed to return elements in numeric order)? Besides `table.insert` is inefficient, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278426/5267751 (also see for other answers)

Answer (score 5):

Here's iterative version for deep merge because I don't like potential stack overflows of recursive.

```
local merge_task = {}
function merge_to_left_o(orig, new)
   merge_task[orig] = new

   local left = orig
   while left ~= nil do
      local right = merge_task[left]
      for new_key, new_val in pairs(right) do
         local old_val = left[new_key]
         if old_val == nil then
            left[new_key] = new_val
         else
            local old_type = type(old_val)
            local new_type = type(new_val)
            if (old_type == "table" and new_type == "table") then
               merge_task[old_val] = new_val
            else
               left[new_key] = new_val
            end
         end
      end
      merge_task[left] = nil
      left = next(merge_task)
   end
end
```

Comment: My comment was meant as a sarcasm: if you escape the recursion because you fear/expect a stack overflow; and then don't check whether your task container overflows your memory, then it doesn't make much sense to escape recursion in the first place.

Comment: @Irfy, "general" memory used for tables in Lua or similar structures in other languages is most often more abundant than call stack space. Of course one should consider which solution is appropriate for particular environment, not just blindly copy/paste one or another.

Answer (score 5):

Doug Currie's answer is the simplest for most cases. If you need more robust merging of tables, consider using the [`merge()`](https://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.tablex.html#merge) method from the [Penlight](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight) library.

```
require 'pl'
pretty.dump(tablex.merge({a=1,b=2}, {c=3,d=4}, true))

-- {
--   a = 1,
--   d = 4,
--   c = 3,
--   b = 2
-- }
```

Comment: What's the third parameter, BTW?

Comment: The third param determines how the tables are merged: `true` for a union, `false` for an intersection.

https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/master/lua/pl/tablex.lua#L554

Answer (score 3):

I preferred James version for its simplicity and use it in my utils.lua - i did add a check for table type for error handling.

```
function merge(a, b)
    if type(a) == 'table' and type(b) == 'table' then
        for k,v in pairs(b) do if type(v)=='table' and type(a[k] or false)=='table' then merge(a[k],v) else a[k]=v end end
    end
    return a
end
```

Thanks for this nice function which should be part of the table class so you could call `a:merge(b)` but doing `table.merge = function(a, b) ...` did not work for me. Could even be compressed to a one liner for the real nerds :)

Answer (score 2):

Like Doug Currie said, you can use his function, but there is a problem with his method. If `first_table` has things in it's `k` index, the function will over write it.

I'm assuming you're trying to merge these tables, not overwrite index's and value's. So this would be my method, it's very similar but is used for merging tables.

```lua
for _, v in pairs(second_table) do table.insert(first_table, v) end
```

*The only problem with this solution is that the index is set as numbers, not as strings*. This will work with tables with numbers as the index, and for tables with strings as their index, use Doug Currie's method.

#### Doug Currie's method:

```lua
for k,v in pairs(second_table) do first_table[k] = v end
```

Comment: Your method insert new `v` with auto-incremented number index, right?

Comment: As posted in a comment earlier on Jimmy liu's answer: "Isn't this solution wrong (as pairs is not guaranteed to return elements in numeric order)? Besides table.insert is inefficient, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278426/5267751 (also see for other answers)" (by user202729)

Answer (score 1):

Extending this great answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283399/1570165, I would like to go with a (pure) functional approach like this one below:

```lua
-- example values
local t1 = { a = 0, b = 2 }
local t2 = { a = 1, c = 3 }

-- merge function that takes functional approach

local merge = function(a, b)
    local c = {}
    for k,v in pairs(a) do c[k] = v end
    for k,v in pairs(b) do c[k] = v end
    return c
end

-- t1 and t2 value still same after merge
print(merge(t1, t2)) -- { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 }
print(t2) -- { a = 1, c = 3 }
print(t1) -- { a = 0, b = 2 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for k,v in pairs(t2) do t1[k] = v end
```

key for string solution