# Concatenate table sequences in lua

Tags: lua

Is there an easy way to concatenate two tables which are sequences? For example

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {5, 6, 7}
c = cat(a,b)
```

where `c` would be the table `{1,2,3,5,6,7}`?

Comment: Try having a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283388/lua-merge-tables) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410862/concatenation-of-tables-in-lua)

Comment: Excellently and precisely worded question. Unfortunately, it is a duplicate of poorer quality questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
function cat(t, ...)  
    local new = {unpack(t)}  
    for i,v in ipairs({...}) do  
        for ii,vv in ipairs(v) do  
            new[#new+1] = vv  
        end  
    end  
    return new  
end
```

It uses iteration to add the elements of each array to a new one.

It's also worth noting that {unpack(t)} will only work if you have less than a specific number of elements, due to how tuples work in Lua. This varies across versions and depending on what you're doing, but if it's small you probably have nothing to worry about.

Comment: You were missing a single space in the first line, that's why the code block didn't work ;) Remember: four spaces make a code :)

Comment: Please note that `{unpack(t)}` only works for up to about one million table elements (or 15000 if you have 16 bit `int`s).

Comment: @siffie Last I checked it was 8K...

Comment: @Henrik Can't believe I missed that. Thanks :D

Comment: @warspyking It's about 8K for Lua 5.1. Both Lua 5.2 and 5.3 can handle 999970 elements in my test cases (depending on how much stack space you already use).

Comment: @siffiejoe Oh, I primarily use Lua 5.1, that's why I thought it was 8K,