# Lua add two tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
x = {1, 2, 3}
y = {4, 5, 6}
z = x + y
```

I have two tables `x` and `y` and just want to create a third one which is just the elements of them two (not sorted). I use the above code in an effort but this gives error `input:3: attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value (global 'x')`...

Comment: If `x = { 1, 2, 3 }` and `y = { 3, 4, 5 }`, should `z = x + y = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` (no duplicates) or `{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 }` (possible duplicates)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenation of tables in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410862/concatenation-of-tables-in-lua)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you want to concatenate the two tables to obtain `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`.

There is no builtin function or operator for that. You can use this code:

```
z = {}
n = 0
for _,v in ipairs(x) do n=n+1; z[n]=v end
for _,v in ipairs(y) do n=n+1; z[n]=v end
```

If you want to use the syntax `z = x + y`, then set an `__add` metamethod. (But perhaps a `__concat` metamethod is more adequate for your meaning.)

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have mentioned, there is no built-in way of doing this. The simplest way of doing it is to define your own function, as in GoojajiGreg's answer. However, if you really want to use the `+` operator, you can use an `__add` metamethod.

```
local metatable = {
    __add = function (t1, t2)
        local ret = {}
        for i, v in ipairs(t1) do
            table.insert(ret, v)
        end
        for i, v in ipairs(t2) do
            table.insert(ret, v)
        end
        return ret
    end
}

local x = {1, 2, 3}
local y = {4, 5, 6}

setmetatable(x, metatable)
setmetatable(y, metatable)

local z = x + y

for i, v in ipairs(z) do
    print(v)
end

-- Output:
-- 1
-- 2
-- 3
-- 4
-- 5
-- 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set function that will sum tables as `__add` metamethod in the metatable that should be set for all tables that needs that implicit behavior. See Lua manual section "Metatables and Metamethods" for details.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a method to return the union of the tables:

```
local function union ( a, b )
    local result = {}
    for k,v in pairs ( a ) do
        table.insert( result, v )
    end
    for k,v in pairs ( b ) do
         table.insert( result, v )
    end
    return result
end
```

This doesn't prevent multiple instances of the same value in the resulting table.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `table.move` to do it:

```
function extend(t1, t2)
    return table.move(t2, 1, #t2, #t1 + 1, t1)
end
```

Example usage:

```
a = {"a", "b"}
b = {"c", "d", "e"}
c = extend(a, b)
```

After this both `a` and `c` contains `{"a, "b", "c", "d", "e"}`, while `b` is still `{"c", "d", "e"}`.