# Using Wireshark Field Occurrence in Display Filter

Tags: wireshark

Using Wireshark 4.2.2, I can create a custom display column that displays the value from a certain field occurrence. I would like to be able to do something similar and use a field occurrence in a display filter, but I cannot find any reference as to how to do that.

Specifically, I am looking at a capture file that contains SIP messages which have a SDP body. In the SDP, there are multiple media lines for each media stream defined. I want to create a display filter that shows when the first media stream supports a certain format and the second media stream does not support that format.

I can create 2 custom custom display columns from the `sdp.media` field, one with Field Occurrence set to 1 and one with Field Occurrence set to 2; and the Wireshark table will properly show the two media streams, 1 in each column. I can inspect these manually for my conditions, but would prefer to create a display filter to help with the inspection.

I have tried something like `sdp.media[1] contains "0" && !sdp.media[2] contains "0"` or `sdp.media#1 contains "0" && !sdp.media#2 contains "0"`. However, I understand that the slice operator (`[1]`) is operating on a byte array rather than field occurrence and the layer operator (`#1`) is operating on the network layer and also not on field occurrence.

Is this possible at all with Wireshark or must I perform manual inspection? Bonus points if I can use the `sdp.media.format` field instead of just `sdp.media`, something like `sdp.media[1].format contains "PCMU" && !sdp.media[2].format contains "PCMU"`.

Comment: Can you post a sample capture file somewhere along with the desired/expected results of applying a suitable display filter, i.e., exactly which packets you would expect to be filtered from the total?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Christopher. I have uploaded an example here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CYMeta17XBuFBvxMOkLVk72HkACk8PQS/view?usp=sharing
In this example, I would expect all of the packets except for packet 11 to be filtered out; only packet 11 should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use a Lua post-dissector to achieve your goal.  For example:

```lua
local sdp_post = Proto("sdp_post", "SDP post-dissector")

local sdp_media_formats = {
    [1] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.1", "Media Format 1"),
    [2] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.2", "Media Format 2"),
    [3] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.3", "Media Format 3"),
    [4] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.4", "Media Format 4"),
    [5] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.5", "Media Format 5"),
    [6] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.6", "Media Format 6"),
    [7] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.7", "Media Format 7"),
    [8] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.8", "Media Format 8"),
    [9] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.9", "Media Format 9"),
    [10] = ProtoField.string("sdp_post.media.format.10", "Media Format 10")
}
sdp_post.fields = sdp_media_formats

local sdp_media_format_f = Field.new("sdp.media.format")

function sdp_post.dissector(tvb, pinfo, tree)

    local sdp_media_format = {sdp_media_format_f()}
    if sdp_media_format then

        local sdp_post_tree = tree:add(sdp_post, "SDP Postdissector: " .. #sdp_media_format .. " Media Formats")

        for i, v in pairs(sdp_media_format) do
            if sdp_media_formats[i] then
                sdp_post_tree:add(sdp_media_formats[i], v.value)
            else
                sdp_post_tree:append_text(" (Only showing the first " .. i-1 .. ")")
                break
            end
        end
    end
end

register_postdissector(sdp_post)
```

---

Save this to a file such as `sdp-postdissector.lua` and place it in your *"Personal Lua Plugins"* directory, which you can find from *"Wireshark: Help -> About Wireshark -> Folders"*.  Once you've done that, either restart Wireshark or use *"Analyze -> Reload Lua Plugins (Ctrl+Shift+L)"* to load it.  Now you should be able to use the `sdp_post.media.format.i` postdissector display filters to achieve your goal.  For example: `sdp_post.media.format.1 contains "PCMA"` will display packets 1 and 11 in your capture file.

**Note**: If you want to work with other sdp fields besides just `sdp.media.format`, then you might want to refer to my answer to this related question: [How to add an array of fields as a ProtoField in Lua Dissector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75379622/how-to-add-an-array-of-fields-as-a-protofield-in-lua-dissector)

Comment: Wow, this is more complicated than I had hoped it would be! Thank you for your answer with the Lua script!