# Insert Additional data into Lua table at index

Tags: lua

I have a table called "inventory", initialized like so:

```
inventory = {}

inventory[1] = { qty = 0 }
```

I want to add more data to this table, at the index 1, eg:

```
val = { id = "example" }

inventory[1] = inventory[1], val
```

Is there a way I can do this while preserving the data that is already in this table at this index?

The final result should be something like:

```
inventory[1] = { qty = 0, id = "example" }
```

But if I try to print the id after trying this code I get:

```
print(inventory[1].id) == Nil
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lua - merge tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283388/lua-merge-tables)

Answer (score 2):

```
inventory[1].id = "example"
```

or

```
inventory[1]["id"] = "example"
```

or

[this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283388/lua-merge-tables) with `first_table` being `inventory[1]` and `second_table` being `val`.

FWIW, you'd need 2 variables on the left side of the expression for `inventory[1] = inventory[1], val` to work: `a, b = x, y`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to do it without having to say specifically inventory[1].id?  The data in val = { id = "example" } may not actually be called id, and may have more than one entry with different names!

Comment: That would be where the other SO answer comes in. That answer contains code to loop through the `val` table and apply key value pairs regardless of the key names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the first key in the table and use it:

```
local inventory = {}
inventory[1] = { qty = 0 }
local val = { id = "example" }

-- 

local KeyName = next(val)

inventory[1][KeyName] = val[KeyName]

print(inventory[1][KeyName]) 
-- or 
print(inventory[1].id)
```